# Mongoose philosophy on being schema based

Tags: django, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoengine

I am currently switching from Django to Node.js. In my django app I used MongoDB and still want to continue with it, reason being flexibility mongo offers (its schema-less).

I was going through mongoosejs. On [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com) website they have used three adjectives for mongoose which are `flexible` `schema-based` and `feature-rich`. After having a broader look at the documentation I have NO doubt that it is feature-rich (features are really impressive). But the other two adjectives seems to contradict from Mongodb philosophy. Mongodb quotes that its dynamic schema offers flexibility. And on the other hand Mongoose is schema based. So in actuality how flexible is Mongoose? I really liked mongodb dynamic schema and wish to have that. **In short**, how feasible is it to make minor alterations in my schema with Mongoose with pre-populated collections.

Also for curiosity sake, I have two queries (kind of related to this question only)

1. can I set any `field` to `undefined` in Mongoose schema
2. can I set any field to `optional` as in mongoengine (Python ORM for mongo).

Comment: mongoose is capable of giving you a base schema with which to work from with fully built in validation rules etc. It should work the same as django with changes to the schema

Comment: Ok, so in case I have extra fields defined, that won't be a problem.

Comment: [opinion]That's the reason why I don't like mongoose: It completely misses the point of MongoDB by trying to press an SQL-like schema on it. The whole point of MongoDB is to get away from a strict schema. When one wants a schema, they should just stick to their SQL database and not pretend to do something new and innovative by using MongoDB as if it were SQL.[/opinion]

Comment: Yup, exactly, you spoke my mind :)

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks dude, I tried it on my test collection. You were right. (at)Philipp By Mongoose Schema we can introduce rigidity as per our need. So as Sammaye quoted and also I have tested, Mongoose provides a means to offer rigidity as per our needs and only provides a base schema.

Comment: It is indeed quite powerful since imagine a normal website with a user object, a user will have a base set of fields at all times, no matter what (so there is actually a schema) but then each user will have their own personal fields you can add on top. So it is quite a powerful framework and it is how a lot of PHP framework do it and my personal opinion is that it works really really well.

Comment: @Sammaye Yes, actually when I first saw, that its schema based, I thought its way too rigid. But after using it I am liking it. What so ever ORM there is for mongo, flexibility must be maintained since its one of the key factors why many people opt for mongo.

Comment: to answer your second question:
you can set any field to {type:YourType, required:false}, it will make that field optional and won't throw a CastError during .save() invokation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some structure even in unstructured data, and there is some schema even if it is schemaless :)

Try to find what all schema you can use with mongoose. If most of your data is having fixed schema, you should use it!

If most of your data is schemaless, dont bother about mongoose!

Yes, it is contradictory, but at the end, rapid prototyping,performance matters! :-)

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, Philipp and Raxit for sharing your opinion. :)